# FATAL EXCEPTION AsyncTask

Tags: android, webview, android-asynctask

In my app im using a hyperlink in my webview with shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) to trigger a Async function... it works fine if a user only presses the link once... But if the user clicks the link multiple times (User is allowed in the app to click the link multiple times) my app closes "Unfortunatley, Your App has Stopped" and I get the following error in my logcat:

```
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983): Process: com.soto.splash, PID: 6983
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:161)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:138)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:455)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:902)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:801)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:780)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at com.soto.splash.network.NetworkOperations.addlike(NetworkOperations.java:681)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at com.soto.splash.Gallery$LongOperation.doInBackground(Gallery.java:648)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at     com.soto.splash.Gallery$LongOperation.doInBackground(Gallery.java:1)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983):     ... 3 more
```

This is my shouldOverrideUrlLoading for webview:

```
      @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if (url.endsWith("&photo")) 
            {
         new LongOperation().execute("");
                return true;
              }
        }
```

Then this is my Async:

```
 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        NetworkOperations.add(url2, "", "");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Is their a solution to fix this issue I'm having with Multiple Asyncs?

Comment: and what will happen when the user click it several times?

Comment: It throws the error thats on the top of this page in my logcat and closes my app giving me this message "Unfortunately, Your App has stopped."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are connecting again and again to the same function/network from a static class..

what happen is that.. let say you are currently executing a network operation through the static class method and again the user click the link which will create another network operation.. now on that time the first network operation connection is still on going but you want to perform another connection which will result to

```
    connection still allocated.
05-05 19:28:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(6983): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
```

what you need to do is create a new instance of that class each time you want to do a network operation.. and pass the result to the `onPostExecute` where youll add the result..

Comment: That makes sense... I'm kinda confuse on "create a new instance of that class"?  How would I approach doing this?

Comment: @user2423476 inside the doInbackground just create a new instance of NetworkOperations... lets say NetworkOperations no = new NetworkOperations(); no.add(url2, "", "");

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following. Make the button not clickeable in onProgressUpdate(....) and make it back clickeable in onPostExecute(...)

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
   <your_button>.setClickable(false);  
}
```

And then make it back clickable in onPostExecute(...)

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
   <your_button>.setClickable(true);  
}
```